# Android: SearchView textView Listener

Tags: android, searchview

Im creating a custom SearchView, but so far I didn't find a (click)event or listener, if the user clicks on the searchView widget, specifically, I need to show a custom fragment when the user clicked the TextView give the SearchView.

much appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [setOnSearchClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setOnSearchClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)). I think it'll do the trick